Why does NtQuerySystemInformation not work with x32 builds?
Within a x32 platform specific compiled exe, I need to get the path for a process (using a process id) without requiring elevated/admin rights. The process path we're looking for may or may not be run by the current user and may or may not be run with elevated privileges. From my understanding the only way to do this is through the undocumented Windows API NtQuerySystemInformation and SystemProcessIdInformation.
I have this working great with x64 builds, but as soon as I try to run the program in x32 all calls to NtQuerySystemInformation return STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH.
Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?
Here's a minimal example of this, just build using x32 and it wont work... but in x64 it will.
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ntstatus.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")

struct SYSTEM_PROCESS_ID_INFORMATION
{
   HANDLE ProcessId;
   UNICODE_STRING ImageName;
};

NTSTATUS GetProcessPath(
   const DWORD pid)
{
   SYSTEM_PROCESS_ID_INFORMATION info;
   info.ProcessId = reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(static_cast<unsigned long long>(pid));
   info.ImageName.Length = 0;
   info.ImageName.MaximumLength = 0;
   info.ImageName.Buffer = nullptr;

   ULONG ReturnLength;
   NTSTATUS status = STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH;
   while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
   {
      if (info.ImageName.Buffer)
      {
         LocalFree(info.ImageName.Buffer);
      }

      info.ImageName.Buffer = static_cast<PWSTR>(LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, info.ImageName.MaximumLength));
      if (!info.ImageName.Buffer)
      {
         status = STATUS_NO_MEMORY;
         break;
      }

      //0x58 = Undocumented SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS::SystemProcessIdInformation
      status = NtQuerySystemInformation(static_cast<SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS>(0x58), &info, sizeof(info), &ReturnLength);
   }

   // Convert status to DWORD: result = RtlNtStatusToDosError(status);
   if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
   {
   
   }

   if (info.ImageName.Buffer)
   {
      LocalFree(info.ImageName.Buffer);
   }

   return status;
}

int main()
{
   // Replace 9200 with a process id (found through Task Manager).
   GetProcessPath(9200);
   return 0;
}


"I need to get the path for a process (using a process id) without requiring elevated/admin rights. From my understanding the only way to do this is through the undocumented Windows API NtQuerySystemInformation and SystemProcessIdInformation" - um, no. You can use GetModuleFileNameEx(), GetProcessImageFileName(), or QueryFullProcessImageName() instead.  All you need is to call OpenProcess() first asking for PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION access. That doesn't require admin rights. You don't need to resort to an undocumented internal API when a documented public API will suffice.

@RemyLebeau my mistake, I forgot to mention that the process path we're looking for may or may not be run by the current user and may or may not be run with elevated privileges.  So I don't expect the methods you listed to work as OpenProcess wont work with processes by other users and/or higher rights. I've edited my original post.

Asking OpenProcess() for PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION access works on elevated processes, and processes of other users. GetModuleFileNameEx() will not work in this case (as it requires SeDebugPrivilege and PROCESS_VM_READ rights), but GetProcessImageFileName() and QueryFullProcessImageName() should work.

Not NtQuerySystemInformation but NtQueryInformationProcess.  Also need another undocumented API NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64. It's more complicated than GetModuleFileNameEx but it can get lots of information including path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714297/is-it-possible-to-read-process-memory-of-a-64-bit-process-from-a-32bit-app/36798492#36798492

@RemyLebeau as far as I can tell it does not. If I try to use it on a SYSTEM process the OpenProcess function always returns ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE. This is what I do...
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, true, pid);

You likely need to enable the SeDebugPrivilege before opening a system process, even with PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION. Do be aware of this, though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28308458/65863

@RemyLebeau That's not something I can do, as this often requires elevated privilege's. I think I've figured out why my original solution wasn't working in x32 builds. Just running some tests before I post the solution

in case wow64 implementation containing bug - it not update MaximumLength when return STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH. and about PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION - it of course enouth for QueryFullProcessImageName but for open process with such access - or process DACL must allow this access for your token ( in case not elevated process - this usually only for your login session) or you must have debug privilege - so be elevated usual

After awhile I realized that the issue was because I issued a MaximumLength for the ImageName buffer as 0, where it should have been assigned a maximum data size for the maximum amount of characters permitted in the buffer (MAX_PATH * sizeof(WCHAR)).
I'm not sure why this did not cause issues in x64 builds (it worked perfectly fine), but did in x32... but here is the fix.
Change
ImageName.MaximumLength = 0;

To
ImageName.MaximumLength = MAX_PATH * sizeof(WCHAR);

